# How to draw curved arrow between two circles in Manim

Tags: python, manim

In Manim community edition, given two circles, how can I draw a curved arrow between the two circles?

You can draw a line between two circles like this:

```
from manim import *


class Curve1(Scene):
    def construct(self):
        c1 = Circle(radius=0.2, color=BLUE)
        c2 = Circle(radius=0.2, color=BLUE)
        group = Group(c1,c2).arrange(buff=1)
        self.add(group)

        line = Line(c1,c2)
        self.add(line)
```

I tried replacing `Line` with `CurvedArrow` like this:

```
from manim import *


class Curve1(Scene):
    def construct(self):
        c1 = Circle(radius=0.2, color=BLUE)
        c2 = Circle(radius=0.2, color=BLUE)
        group = Group(c1,c2).arrange(buff=1)
        self.add(group)
        curve = CurvedArrow(c1,c2)
        self.add(curve)
```

That fails as shown below, presumably because `CurvedArrow`'s constructor wants two points as the (start,end) position rather than two objects.  Is there a way to get the positions of the two circles?

```
Manim Community v0.12.0

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/manim/mobject/mobject.py:1652: VisibleDeprecationWarning: Creating an ndarray from nested sequences exceeding the maximum number of dimensions of 32 is deprecated. If you mean to do this, you must specify 'dtype=object' when creating the ndarray.
  target_vect = np.array(end) - np.array(start)
╭─────────────────────────────── Traceback (most recent call last) ────────────────────────────────╮
│                                                                                                  │
│ /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/manim/cli/render/commands.py:139 in render                │
│                                                                                                  │
│   136 │   │   for SceneClass in scene_classes_from_file(file):                                   │
│   137 │   │   │   try:                                                                           │
│   138 │   │   │   │   scene = SceneClass()                                                       │
│ ❱ 139 │   │   │   │   scene.render()                                                             │
│   140 │   │   │   except Exception:                                                              │
│   141 │   │   │   │   error_console.print_exception()                                            │
│   142 │   │   │   │   sys.exit(1)                                                                │
│ /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/manim/scene/scene.py:216 in render                        │
│                                                                                                  │
│    213 │   │   """                                                                               │
│    214 │   │   self.setup()                                                                      │
│    215 │   │   try:                                                                              │
│ ❱  216 │   │   │   self.construct()                                                              │
│    217 │   │   except EndSceneEarlyException:                                                    │
│    218 │   │   │   pass                                                                          │
│    219 │   │   except RerunSceneException as e:                                                  │
│                                                                                                  │
│ /manim/curve.py:14 in construct                                                                  │
│                                                                                                  │
│   11 │   │   line = Line(c1,c2)                                                                  │
│   12 │   │   self.add(line)                                                                      │
│   13 │   │                                                                                       │
│ ❱ 14 │   │   curve = CurvedArrow(c1,c2)                                                          │
│   15 │   │   self.add(curve)                                                                     │
│   16                                                                                             │
│                                                                                                  │
│ /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/manim/mobject/geometry.py:470 in __init__                 │
│                                                                                                  │
│    467 class CurvedArrow(ArcBetweenPoints):                                                      │
│    468 │   def __init__(self, start_point, end_point, **kwargs):                                 │
│    469 │   │   tip_shape = kwargs.pop("tip_shape", ArrowTriangleFilledTip)                       │
│ ❱  470 │   │   super().__init__(start_point, end_point, **kwargs)                                │
│    471 │   │   self.add_tip(tip_shape=tip_shape)                                                 │
│    472                                                                                           │
│    473                                                                                           │
│                                                                                                  │
│ /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/manim/mobject/geometry.py:457 in __init__                 │
│                                                                                                  │
│    454 │   │   super().__init__(radius=radius, angle=angle, **kwargs)                            │
│    455 │   │   if angle == 0:                                                                    │
│    456 │   │   │   self.set_points_as_corners([LEFT, RIGHT])                                     │
│ ❱  457 │   │   self.put_start_and_end_on(start, end)                                             │
│    458 │   │                                                                                     │
│    459 │   │   if radius is None:                                                                │
│    460 │   │   │   center = self.get_arc_center(warning=False)                                   │
│                                                                                                  │
│ /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/manim/mobject/mobject.py:1652 in put_start_and_end_on     │
│                                                                                                  │
│   1649 │   │   curr_vect = curr_end - curr_start                                                 │
│   1650 │   │   if np.all(curr_vect == 0):                                                        │
│   1651 │   │   │   raise Exception("Cannot position endpoints of closed loop")                   │
│ ❱ 1652 │   │   target_vect = np.array(end) - np.array(start)                                     │
│   1653 │   │   axis = (                                                                          │
│   1654 │   │   │   normalize(np.cross(curr_vect, target_vect))                                   │
│   1655 │   │   │   if np.linalg.norm(np.cross(curr_vect, target_vect)) != 0                      │
│                                                                                                  │
│ /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/manim/mobject/mobject.py:507 in __sub__                   │
│                                                                                                  │
│    504 │   │   return self                                                                       │
│    505 │                                                                                         │
│    506 │   def __sub__(self, other):                                                             │
│ ❱  507 │   │   raise NotImplementedError                                                         │
│    508 │                                                                                         │
│    509 │   def __isub__(self, other):                                                            │
│    510 │   │   raise NotImplementedError                                                         │
╰──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────╯
NotImplementedError
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I think I found it.  The position of the circle's center is `circle.get_center()`.